# Compare two XML files and update elements in one of them

Tags: python, xml

I am sorry if my title sounds confusing.
I am writing a Python script that compares 2 XML files. In both files we have data for which the id's are equal to those in the other file.

E.g.

Source file:

```
  <id>123456</id> 
    <data>blabla</data>
        ......some other data......
  <id>abcde</id>
    <data>gfkgjk</data>
        ......some more data..........
```

Target file:

```
  <id>123456</id> 
    <data> </data>
        ......some other data......
  <id>ghijk</id>
    <data>gfkgjk</data>
        ......some more data..........
```

As you can see in the above examples, not all ID's that are in the source file are also in the target file. Furthermore, although 2 data groups have the same ID, one has the "data" tags filled out, the other hasn't.

My programme is supposed to have a look at the source file, extract the id and the text between the data tags. Then it looks into the target file, and if there is data with the same ID and empty data tags (like in the example above), it fills in these empty tags with the information from the source file. (By the way: apart from the ID and the data information, the two XMLs are completely different, therefore I can't just keep the source file).

Right, I was able to extract the ID and the info between the data tags.
Now I'm trying to write a function to compare the ids and replace the empty data info if there is one. 
However, I'm not very familiar with Python and functions and need some help.
Here is what my function looks like:

```
def replace_empty_data():
    for x in xmlData_id_source:
       if xmlData_id_source==xmlData_id_target:
          target = re.sub(xmlData_2,xmlData,target)
       return target
    file_target.close()
```

There's probably loads missing in the function, but I don't know what. It doesn't give me any errors and is simply not working. Variables except x have been defined in earlier parts of the code, so this is not an issue.

xmlData_id_source is the ID from the source file
xmlData_id_target is the ID from the target file
xmlData_2 is the data information from the target file
xmlData is the data information from the source file

Thanks for the input so far, but I'm still looking for an easy-to-understand method for someone who has no clue about programming....I used minidom for parsing the files and would like to use it without importing and installing further libraries.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an XML Parser for this. Take a look at [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).

**Do not use regular expressions or string substitution here**.

Comment: I am using Minidom, which worked fine. The only question left is how I write this compare function after I extracted the data.

Answer (score 1):

I use [lxml](http://lxml.de/), which has good performance and additional functionalities such as XPATH that the builtin ElementTree does not support. Here is what I'd do:

```
>>> source = """<root>
    <tag>
        <id>123456</id> 
        <data>blabla</data>
    </tag>
    <tag>
        <id>abcde</id>
        <data>gfkgjk</data>
    </tag>
</root>"""
>>> target = """<root>
    <tag>
        <id>123456</id> 
        <data> </data>
    </tag>
    <tag>
        <id>ghijk</id>
        <data>gfkgjk</data>
    </tag>
</root>"""
```

Since the `data` node is not encapsulated in the `id` one, I assumed that they both were in a `tag` one, which is somewhere under a `root`. Ok, 1st part aims at getting a dict of `id`s and their corresponding `data`:

```
>>> root = etree.fromstring(source)
>>> for tag in root.findall('tag'):
    id_ = tag.find('id')
    data = tag.find('data')
    id_dict[id_.text] = data.text


>>> id_dict
{'123456': 'blabla', 'abcde': 'gfkgjk'}
```

Now, update target thanks to this dict:

```
>>> root = etree.fromstring(target)
>>> for tag in root.findall('tag'):
    id_ = tag.find('id')
    data = tag.find('data')
    if data.text.strip() == '':
        data.text = id_dict[id_.text]


>>> print etree.tostring(root)
<root>
    <tag>
        <id>123456</id> 
        <data>blabla</data>
    </tag>
    <tag>
        <id>ghijk</id>
        <data>gfkgjk</data>
    </tag>
</root>
```

You just have to adapt that solution to your real XML structure and that should be good !

Comment: Thank you, that sounds like a convenient thing to do. I just hoped there might be a way I could use Python internal tools because the code is going to be distributed within my company for people who are not really familiar with installing loads of stuff before being able to run a programme! Mhhh...anyway, will give it a try! Thanks :)

Comment: Well, ElementTree and lxml are similar so since here I used very basic functionalities (`findall`, `find`, `.text`...) there is a chance that you can use it as is or with a small adaptation effort.

Comment: I am still trying to get my head around this. I've been trying to adjust your code to the built-in etree, but my problem is that I receive the error that "id_dict" is not defined. is the id_dict[id_.text] thing specific to lxml?